# How to ES6 Proxy an ArrayBuffer or Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, webcrypto-api, es6-proxy

These work:

```
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', new Uint8Array([0]))
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', new Uint8Array([0]).buffer)
```

These don't:

```
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', new Proxy(new Uint8Array([0]),{}))
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', new Proxy(new Uint8Array([0]).buffer,{})
```

Error:

`Failed to execute 'digest' on 'SubtleCrypto': The provided value is not of type '(ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView)'`

`instanceof Uint8Array` and `instanceof ArrayBuffer` return true in both cases.

Comment: Looks like the native `crypto.subtle.digest` function needs a real typed array, not a proxy. Even if they're otherwise indistinguishable to javascript.

Comment: What are you trying to do, why do you want to use a proxy here?

Comment: @Bergi, I want to pass it a file in slices by hijacking whatever access method it uses. Loading an ArrayBuffer of 1.2GB or more crashes the tab.

Comment: You can perfectly slice a file (Blob or ArrayBuffer) without using a proxy? Though I'm not sure how you meant to use the proxy to lower memory usage anyway.

Comment: Native crypto doesn't support `.update(data)` for hashing. You give it one `ArrayBuffer` and it returns a promise for an `ArrayBuffer` of the hash. End of story.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question about how you intended to use a proxy to emulate `update`, though.

Comment: I was planning to give it the first slice, then, when it reaches the end, dispose of it and start feeding the next slice, and so on.

I have pretty much accepted this as impossible right now, it clearly wants the buffer for its backend implementation and not for its JavaScript API.

Comment: IIRC, all methods load a slice of a file representation that didn't already allocate the data into a buffer are asynchronous, so I don't think this would have worked anyway.

Comment: What would proxying ArrayBuffer give you? It doesn't look like you can intercept gets and sets the underlying data, since there's no ability to get or set from an ArrayBuffer originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`digest` is specified by its IDL interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#subtlecrypto-interface) to only accept a `BufferSource`, which is [either an `ArrayBufferView` or an `ArrayBuffer`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL-1/#common-BufferSource). This IDL-level typing indicates that a correct implementation will categorically reject any inputs that doesn't have the correct internal type.

Any tricks you might want to use a `Proxy` for simply aren't going to work on `digest`. Instead, you could do proxy tricks to get the exact `ArrayBuffer` you want immediately before you pass in your data to `digest`.

For example, here's a proxy that fakes a `buffer` that differs from the `buffer` on its internal object. The `buffer` is genuine, so it can be passed into `digest`, but it was created by `Proxy` magic:

```
var proxy = new Proxy(new Uint8Array([0]), {
                          get:function(obj, prop) {
                              if(prop=="buffer"){ return new Uint8Array([42]).buffer }
                              else { return obj[prop]; }
                          }
            });
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', proxy.buffer)
```

If it is impossible to produce the buffer (for example if it is too big to fit in RAM) you would currently have to rely on something other than SubtleCrypto.

This seems like a great point to raise with the W3C, e.g., to support an `update` mechanism to iteratively collect input.

Comment: The ArrayBuffer I want is illegal. Because it is too big.

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis You may be out of luck, then. You might need to see if you can use a non-native implementation that supports incremental updates. This seems like a great point to raise with the W3C. Also, for certain hashes, it may be possible to do an incremental update (e.g., [this Crypto.SE post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9195/1643) hints that you can write some combining function `F` yourself such that `F(Hash(s1), s2) == Hash(s1 + s2)` for SHA-1, -2, and -3), but you'd need to consult with a hash expert to create such a function, if it exists for a given hash algorithm.

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis So it looks such a function `F(oldHash, newInput)` is possible for SHA-1 and SHA-2 family functions (including 512), but it is not possible for SHA-3 family functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack for how to start implementing such a function.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way (`H(F(H(s1),s2`) before going to pure js solutions.
However, even it can defeat one iteration's padding, having to load state into the SHA-512 machine means the native function won't work once more.

Comment: Perhaps I should look into doing it in wasm, it's supported on mobile now (which is where the pure js hurt the most)